# looking for any tool to detect the type of the string to it's Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

I'm looking for any tool to detect the type of the string to it's Unicode !

I have data stored at the database in the format "Ø³ÙˆØ±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù†Ø§Ø³"
it equivalent to data in Arabic to "سورة الناس"

I 'm trying to do that because I'm working on Arabic framework and it uses a special kind of Unicode conversion that I don't know

Comment: u have data stored in that format ... i dont think you can "reconvert" it once it goes to bunk, because that translation should have happened before insert. its like asking someone to unhash something.

Comment: it's in a huge backup data , about 11000 record and it seems no one know how to convert it !

Comment: the problem is when I insert new data  , so it becomes  we have 2 format data , the Unicode data E.G "Ø³ÙˆØ±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù†Ø§Ø³" and the new Arabic data E.G "أ ب"

Comment: its not a matter of size man ... its a matter of it not being able to retrieve it. the original coding type couldnt read what it was so it invented characters, there is no "translation" back.

Comment: this is another issue , so I'm asking how to detect the type of Unicode of that text ! other wise I will go on it with try and error but would be very hard !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example, it seems that the data is simply UTF-8 encoded. The string “"Ø³ÙˆØ±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù†Ø§Ø³” is what you get if you have the text “سورة الناس” as UTF-8 encoded and you misinterpret it as windows-1252 encoded.

So if all data is like that, you don’t need any conversions. You should simply do all the character processing on the basis of the UTF-8 encoding.

When working with PHP, the answers to the question [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) are probably very useful.

Comment: thanks alot it works now with me I used  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'windows-1252'");
                mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET windows-1252");
                mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'windows-1252'"); before the sql query and it execute the same , thanks a million , you helped me too much by this Unicode :) thanks :)